# How to find the number of bytes of parameters passed to the function?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, mingw

I am using mingw64 to compile a *DLL*.

I have read that:

The name decoration for `__sdtdcall-declared` functions in MinGW is `FunctionName@nn`, where `@nn` is the number of bytes of parameters passed to the function. By this mechanism, it's not possible to call a function with the 'wrong' type, or even with the wrong number of parameters.

My question is as in the title: How to find the number of bytes of parameters passed to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizeof(type) function gives the number of bytes for a particulat data type.

Examples:

```
    See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof
```

If your asking about strings ( char * ):

```
    See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlen#strlen
```

Comment: strlen will not tell you anything about the stack space used to pass the argument.

Comment: @NiklasB. Correct - Stack space used by a string is going to be sizeof(char *) but I don't think the author is looking for stack space used.

Comment: He's asking for that, however, as with the `@nn` name decoration for stdcall, `nn` stands for the accumulated stack space used by the actual parameters.